# MySQL Connector.NET-8.0.26 not uninstalling/removing

Tags: mysql, uninstallation, mysql-connector

using the wizard to remove mysql connector.net wont remove it... shows this [ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbOIi.png)

please help.. I want to uninstall this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. This is what I did-

completely unistalled Mysql using BCUninstaller.
Deleted keys and subkeys of MySql from registry. (you can use 'find'--> ctrl+F)
Reinstalled. And found the same welcome message which failed to upgrade Connector.NET-8.0.26.

Main solution:-

1. Opened regedit and searched for Connector-NET-8.0.26 (In my case I found it here: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\9D08D5A3CA3B01049B489CEB6FAD579C you may copy/paste and look there among the files.)
2. Deleted the folder and reinstalled.

It successfully upgraded the connector and I had to add rest of the components manually.